# звать/позвать and звонить/позвонить - What are the differences between these verbs?

Tags: перевод, значения

I know there is perfective and imperfective verb structure in interesting Russian language such as гулять(imperf) and погулять(perf). However after i've tried to translate those 2 verbs in the question title, i came across with same equivalent which is the verb "to call" and that made me a bit confused. Can you explain difference(s) with examples in English and Russian. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Звонить** is the phone verb. In Russian, you don't call but "ring" someone on the phone. **Звать** is the general calling verb, as in shouting after someone or referring to what someone is named. **Позвонить** and **позвать** are their respective perfective pairs.

There is yet another equivalent of the English "call", and it's **называть**. It means "call" in the narrow sense of "refer to as"; it's the one you use when talking about what inanimate objects are called (**В Петербурге бордюр называют поребриком** "In St Petersburg, a kerb is called *porebrik*"), and when talking about something that a person is called which isn't a name (**Многие называют его шарлатаном** — "Many are calling him a quack".) The perfective of **называть** is **назвать**. The reflexive form **называться** is also often used in the sense of "to be called".

Comment: In the latter case, "звать" can also be used. *"В Петербурге бордюр зовут поребриком"*. *"Многие зовут его шарлатаном"*.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy It's markedly colloquial, though, isn't it?

Comment: perfect answer! instead of the verb "to call" in english exist 3 different verbs in russian! and i realized its definitely natural because those 3 verbs are related to 3 different concepts! this means russian is really much richer language than our tovarish english!:) thank you sir!

Comment: @NikolayErshov It certainly sounds less formal, but I wouldn't call it colloquial. "Бывало, писывала кровью / Она в альбомы нежных дев, / *Звала Полиною Прасковью* / И говорила нараспев;" Your mileage may vary, though.

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz I wouldn't be so definite about language richness :) You need at least two English words for Russian "_звонить_" - "to call" and "to ring". An _to toll_ is "звонить" too.

Answer (score 2):

*Звать* essentially means to use *a voice*, that is to cry for someone or smth. Although there is yet another meaning - to refer to smth., to give a name to someone - but it's clear that "a name" is just a thing said in "voice".

*Звонить* means *to ring a bell*, that is to make some noise by using an object. It applies to door bells, or telephone ring etc.